# How to get next occurance of an rrule for different timezones

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, moment-timezone, rrule

I have an app that allows users to schedule tasks. Users can set a schedule (`schedule`, an rrule string) as well as a timezone (`scheduleTimeZone`, a string e.g. `Asia/Dubai`).

I am trying to write a function (`getNextRunAt`) that gets the next occurrence of the task at a UTC date and store this in my Postgres DB as a `timestamptz` field.

I'm struggling to account for DST, lots of the results are an hour or even a day off.

Here's the function (in TypeScript):

```
import RRule from 'rrule';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

const getNextRunAt = ({
  schedule,
  scheduleTimeZone,
}: {
  schedule?: string | null;
  scheduleTimeZone?: string | null;
}): Date | undefined => {
  if (!schedule) {
    return undefined;
  }
  const options = RRule.parseString(schedule);
  if (scheduleTimeZone) {
    options.tzid = scheduleTimeZone;
  }
  const dtstart = moment.utc().toDate();
  const rule = new RRule({ ...options, dtstart, count: 1 });
  const dates = rule.all();
  let date = dates[0];
  if (scheduleTimeZone && moment(date).tz(scheduleTimeZone).isDST()) {
    date = moment(date).subtract(1, 'hour').toDate();
  }
  return date;
};

export default getNextRunAt;
```

It works for some dates/times/timezones:

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date('2021-03-02 10:24:27.000000Z').getTime());
const nextDate = getNextRunAt({
          schedule: 'RRULE:INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,SA,FR,SU;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=9;BYSECOND=0;FREQ=DAILY',
          scheduleTimeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
        });
expect(nextDate).toEqual(new Date('2021-03-02 17:00:00.000000Z'));
// WORKS
```

But not for others:

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date('2021-03-02 10:24:27.000000Z').getTime());
const nextDate = getNextRunAt({
          schedule: 'RRULE:INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,SA,FR,SU;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=9;BYSECOND=0;FREQ=DAILY',
          scheduleTimeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
        });
expect(nextDate).toEqual(new Date('2021-03-02 17:00:00.000000Z'));
// DOES NOT WORK
Expected: 2021-03-02T17:00:00.000Z
Received: 2021-03-03T17:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: `Date.now = jest.fn(...);` does not look like a good idea. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the last case is wrong with a day. But for others solution might look like:

```
const getNextRunAt = ({ schedule, scheduleTimeZone }: { schedule?: string | null; scheduleTimeZone?: string | null }): Date | undefined => {
if (!schedule) {
    return undefined;
}
const options = RRule.parseString(schedule);

const dtstart = moment();

const rule = new RRule({
    ...options,
    dtstart: dtstart.toDate(),
    count: 1,
});
const dates = rule.all();
const date = dates[0];
let mDate = moment.tz(date, scheduleTimeZone);
const offset = Math.abs(mDate.utcOffset()) > 16 ? mDate.utcOffset() / 60 : mDate.utcOffset();

if (!mDate.isDST()) {
    mDate = mDate.add(1, 'hours');
}

mDate.add(-offset, 'hour');

return mDate.toDate();};
```

Comment: The [moment.js *utcOffset* method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) returns the offset in minutes, so `Math.abs(mDate.utcOffset()) > 16` will mostly be true as offsets are generally multiples of 30 minutes, so only places observing +0 (GMT/UTC) will be false.